# Property cannot be accessed from parent class in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

So I passed some property from parent class(Counters) to child class (counter)

The way I am passing properties:
[image: The way I am passing properties]

and I think it has been correctly passed down I printed "this.props" on console:
[image: i printed "this.props" on console]

but the thing when I am trying to access value of counter via **this.props.counter.value** it's throwing error and also when I am trying to console "**this.props.counter**" it is showing "**undefined**"

Comment: are you using a functional component or class component for `<Counters />`

Comment: i am using class component for Counters

Comment: can you share the code for `<Counters />`

Comment: thank you so much but the suggested answer by @Xesenix worked .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use properties as follow:

```
{this.props.counters.map((counter) => 
  <Counter
    key={counter.id}
    onDelete={this.props.onDelete}
    onIncrement={this.props.onIncrement}
    counter={counter}
  ></Counter>
}
```

You have prematurly closed `<Counter`